# txpool.content return empty object

Tags: synchronization, pending-transactions, txpool, full-node

I opened a full node successfully (I succeed getting data from e.g eth_getTransactionByHash).
I'm trying to get all pending transactions, but I get:

```
> txpool.content
{
  pending: {},
  queued: {}
}
> txpool.status
{
  pending: 0,
  queued: 0
}
```

I tried to sync the server the best I can, but I always get 0 results.
I'm running my server with:

```
geth console --http --http.addr <myip> --http.port "8584" --syncmode fast --cache 8096 --cache.database 100 --cache.trie 100 --cache.gc 100 --cache.snapshot 100 --cache.trie.rejournal 0h0m10s --txpool.rejournal 0h0m10s --txpool.globalslots 50000
```

How can I get the pending transactions?

Comment: Is the node fully synced? Has it enough peers? Does it change if you use the default txpool parameters?

Comment: @Ismael I tried to run it with --syncmode full as well, didn't help, net.peersCount gives 16. What are the default txpool parameters?

Comment: If the node is fully synced I don't know what the problem would be. You can increase the verbosity level and look at the logs for clues.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be that you're not enabling the txpool API, you can do so with the following flag:

--http.api personal,eth,net,web3,txpool